# Fetch GIF File in Fresco With Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, fresco

I have a `recyclerview` that displays a list of images in the GIF format using Fresco, a library for Android.

When the user clicks on an image in the `recyclerview`, I need to be able to fetch the `.gif` file and store it as `somename.gif`

I tried this code:

```
val contentRequest = ImageRequest.fromUri(items[position])
val cacheKey = DefaultCacheKeyFactory.getInstance().getEncodedCacheKey(contentRequest, null)
val imageResource = ImagePipelineFactory.getInstance().mainFileCache.getResource(cacheKey)
val file = (imageResource as FileBinaryResource).file

Log.d("VED-APP", file.name)
```

But the result ends up being: `Lw0g1Jq7J0jUxSCCEZe3UwRa6-0.cnt`, which is different from "somename.gif".

So, I tried this code instead:

```
val contentRequest = ImageRequest.fromUri(items[position])
val imagePipeline = Fresco.getImagePipeline()
val dataSource : DataSource<CloseableReference<CloseableImage>> =
                    imagePipeline.fetchDecodedImage(contentRequest, null)
```

But, the problem is, I need to write the object `dataSource` to a file.

I found this code sample that could help me write `dataSource` to a file, but I don't know how to convert it into Kotlin. Could someone help me out in converting this?

Or, if anyone knows of a better way to fetch files from Fresco, could they suggest an alternative method?

```
DataSource<CloseableReference<T>> dataSource = ...;

DataSubscriber<CloseableReference<T>> dataSubscriber =
    new BaseDataSubscriber<CloseableReference<T>>() {
      @Override
      protected void onNewResultImpl(
          DataSource<CloseableReference<T>> dataSource) {
        if (!dataSource.isFinished()) {
          // if we are not interested in the intermediate images,
          // we can just return here.
          return;
        }
        CloseableReference<T> ref = dataSource.getResult();
        if (ref != null) {
          try {
            // do something with the result
            T result = ref.get();
            ...
          } finally {
            CloseableReference.closeSafely(ref);
          }
        }
      }

      @Override
      protected void onFailureImpl(DataSource<CloseableReference<T>> dataSource) {
        Throwable t = dataSource.getFailureCause();
        // handle failure
      }
    };

dataSource.subscribe(dataSubscriber, executor);
```

**Important Update One** -

I figured out how to convert most of the above code to Kotlin. The only problem is that I don't know how to use the appropriate `executor` to subscribe to the `dataSubscriber`, see the code below for clarification.

According to the [documentation](http://frescolib.org/docs/datasources-datasubscribers.html), I should be using a background thread executor, but I'm not sure how to do that in Kotlin.

```
        val dataSubscriber : DataSubscriber<CloseableReference<CloseableImage>> =
                object : BaseDataSubscriber<CloseableReference<CloseableImage>>() {
                    override fun onNewResultImpl(dataSource: DataSource<CloseableReference<CloseableImage>>?) {

                        if(!dataSource!!.isFinished) {
                            return
                        }

                        val ref : CloseableReference<CloseableImage>? = dataSource.result

                        if(ref != null) {
                            try {
                                val result = ref.get()
                            } finally {
                                CloseableReference.closeSafely(ref)
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onFailureImpl(dataSource: DataSource<CloseableReference<CloseableImage>>?) {
                        Log.d("VED-APP","Fresco Failed to Fetch?")
                    }
                }

        val contentRequest = ImageRequest.fromUri(items[position])
        val imagePipeline = Fresco.getImagePipeline()

        val dataSource : DataSource<CloseableReference<CloseableImage>> =
                imagePipeline.fetchDecodedImage(contentRequest, null)

        dataSource.subscribe(dataSubscriber,/*I don't know what to put here */)
```

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution?